# ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' for Django 3.2.8

Tags: python, django, url, python-import, django-urls

My program got "ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'" for Django version 3.2.8 suddenly. It can work hours before... . How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`django.conf.urls.url()` was deprecated in Django 3.0, and it is removed in last versions of Django.

Have you made an update?

you can use instead of `url`:

`path` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#path

`re-path` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path

for example:

Old code:

```
url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
```

New code

```
path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
```